# Java array help (fixed)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random

I posted a question earlier without trying it out because I was so lost. I tried it out and got some of it done using Google. Here are the questions:

--

Write a method sumWithoutSmallest that computes the sum of an array of values, except for the smallest one, in a single loop, update the sum and the smallest value. After the loop, return the difference.

Add a method removeMin to the previous question that removes the minimum score.

Prompt the user to enter the size of your array, and then use a random number generator to generate different integer numbers to initialize your array.

--

Here's what I have:

--

```
 public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            sumWithoutSmallest();
        }
        public static int sumWithoutSmallest()
        {  
            int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            int smallestNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int sum = 0; 
            for (int i : numbers) 
            { 
                if(smallestNum > i)
                smallestNum = i; 
                sum=sum+i;
            } 
            sum=sum-smallestNum;
            System.out.println(sum); 
            return sum - smallestNum; 
        }
    }

--
```

I'm stuck on the 2nd question. How I understand it, it's asking me to remove the element with the lowest value, but is it even possible to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new array. Btw, posting an alternative way to write the first question too.

```
int []numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int smallest = numbers[0];
int sum = 0;

// Find smallest
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];

    if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = numbers[i];
    }   
}
int sumWithoutSmallest = sum - smallest;

// Remove smallest
int [numbers.length - 1]numbersWithoutSmallest = new int[numbers.length - 1];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] != smallest) {
        numbersWithoutSmallest[index++] = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Btw, your question says nothing about what should be done if there are multiple smallest values in the array. My suggestion will simply ignore all values that matches the lowest one, so if 2 is lowest and there are two 2s, none of them will be added.

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors on the line 

int [numbers.length - 1]numbersWithoutSmallest = new int[numbers.length - 1];